# What does $w(t) ∈ \mathcal{L}^1$ mean?

Tags: functions, notation

I am reading a paper where it is mentioned the following:

> The function $w(t) ∈ \mathcal{L}^1$, where $w(t) ≥ 0$

so what does $\mathcal{L}^1$ mean here?

Comment: Most likely the set of absolutely integrable functions (either with or without a.e. identification). But it depends on context.

Comment: @Iwassuspendedfortalking so basically L1-norm integrable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most contexts in math, the set $\mathcal{L}_1$ is the set of all such functions from a space $X$ to either $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ that are absolutely integrable:

$$ \mathcal{L}_1 = \left\{ f:X \to \mathbb{C} : \int_X |f| dx < \infty \right\} $$

In measure theory, the functions are measurable and the integral is $\int_X |f| d\mu$

Comment: ok, then should $\mathcal{L}_2$ mean second-norm integrable? or L2 norm integrable? or there is no such thing as $\mathcal{L}_2$ ?

Comment: yes, just to be explicit it means $(\int_X |f|^2 dx)^{1/2} < \infty$.  Same for other positive integers $p > 0$, just replace $2$ with $p$

Comment: Allright that is more understandable now! thanks! Is is also called Lebesgue measure?